# Flutter object is not initialized inside function

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter, and i bumped into a problem.

I have a Datum model in my app that looks like this:

```
class Datum {
  Datum({
    this.id,
    this.boxId,
    this.userId,
    this.revisionType,
    this.revisionDate,
    this.revisionLocation,
    this.revisionTitle,
    this.kilometragePourVidange,
    this.repeatRevision,
    this.revisionStatus,
    this.kilometrageLastVidange,
    this.kilometrageRevision,
  });

  int id;
  int boxId;
  int userId;
  String revisionType;
  DateTime revisionDate;
  String revisionLocation;
  String revisionTitle;
  int kilometragePourVidange;
  int repeatRevision;
  int revisionStatus;
  dynamic kilometrageLastVidange;
  int kilometrageRevision;

  factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        id: json["id"],
        boxId: json["box_id"],
        userId: json["user_id"],
        revisionType: json["revision_type"],
        revisionDate: DateTime.parse(json["revision_date"]),
        revisionLocation: json["revision_location"],
        revisionTitle: json["revision_title"],
        kilometragePourVidange: json["kilometrage_pour_vidange"] == null
            ? null
            : json["kilometrage_pour_vidange"],
        repeatRevision: json["repeat_revision"],
        revisionStatus: json["revision_status"],
        kilometrageLastVidange: json["kilometrage_last_vidange"],
        kilometrageRevision: json["Kilometrage_revision"] == null
            ? null
            : json["Kilometrage_revision"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "box_id": boxId,
        "user_id": userId,
        "revision_type": revisionType,
        "revision_date":
            "${revisionDate.year.toString().padLeft(4, '0')}-${revisionDate.month.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}-${revisionDate.day.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}",
        "revision_location": revisionLocation,
        "revision_title": revisionTitle,
        "kilometrage_pour_vidange":
            kilometragePourVidange == null ? null : kilometragePourVidange,
        "repeat_revision": repeatRevision,
        "revision_status": revisionStatus,
        "kilometrage_last_vidange": kilometrageLastVidange,
        "Kilometrage_revision":
            kilometrageRevision == null ? null : kilometrageRevision,
      };
}
```

Now i have my setRevision() that i'm trying to send data to server . My problem is when i inpect data before sending it ==> i find it empty

**print(datum.repeatRevision); == empty
print(datum.revisionTitle); == empty**

```
  void setRevision() async {
   if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      datum.kilometragePourVidange =
          num.parse(_Kilometrage_revisionController.text);
      datum.revisionType = status.toString();
      datum.revisionTitle = _eventController.text;
      datum.revisionLocation = _EmplacementController.text;
      datum.revisionDate = _DateController.text as DateTime;
      datum.repeatRevision = status1;
      datum.kilometrageRevision =
          num.parse(_Kilometrage_revisionController.text);

print(datum.repeatRevision);
print(datum.revisionTitle);

 revisionApi
          .setRevision(
   datum.revisionTitle,
        datum.revisionType,
        datum.revisionDate,
        datum.revisionLocation,
        datum.repeatRevision,
        datum.kilometrageRevision,
        datum.kilometragePourVidange,
      )
 .then((data) {
        if (data != null) {
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(data)));
   }).catchError((error) {
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
            .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(error.toString())));
      });
      setState(() {});
      _KilometrageController.clear();
      _eventController.clear();
      _EmplacementController.clear();
      _DateController.clear();
      _revision_agenceController.clear();
      _Kilometrage_revisionController.clear();

      Navigator.pop(context);

      //
    }
  }

Future<Datum> setRevision(
    String revision_type,
    String revision_title,
    DateTime revision_date,
    String revision_location,
    int kilometrage_pour_vidange,
    int repeat_revision,
    int kilometrage_revision,
  ) async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String token = localStorage.getString('access_token');
    await checkInternet();
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer $token'
    };
    Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'revision_type': revision_type,
      if (revision_title.isNotEmpty) 'revision_title': revision_title,
      'revision_date': revision_date,
      'revision_location': revision_location,
      'kilometrage_pour_vidange': kilometrage_pour_vidange,
      'repeat_revision': repeat_revision,
      'revision_agence': revision_location,
      'kilometrage_revision': kilometrage_revision,
    };
    print(body);
    try {
      final response = await http
          .post(Uri.parse(ApiUtil.SET_REVISION),
              headers: headers, body: jsonEncode(body))
          .timeout(const Duration(seconds: 15));
      final responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body);


      var data = body['message'];
      switch (response.statusCode) {
        case 200:
          throw Exception(data);
    if (response.statusCode != 200) throw Exception(responseBody['message']);
    } on TimeoutException catch (e) {
      throw ('The connection has timed out, Please try again!');
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error?.message ?? 'Server is down');
    }
  }
```

And this is initState()

```
 final datum = Datum();

    @override
      void initState() {
        WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
          getTask1().then((val) => setState(() {
                _events = val;
              }));
        });
        super.initState();
        _controller = CalendarController();
        _eventController = TextEditingController();
        _events = {};
        initializeDateFormatting();
        _selectedEvents = [];
        prefsData();
      }
```

How i can correct it ?
thanks in advance

Comment: After filling data members of datum object, pass datum object to setRevision() function instead of each data member. In set revision function do following. body = jsonEncode(datum.toJson());

Comment: What does "empty" mean?  Do you mean that they're `null`?  How do you know that `Datum` wasn't constructed with `null` values for those members?

Comment: You can that before sending it to last set revision function. no need to create map again in before API call. datum.toJson() will give you map object. When filling datum object, you can add conditions like datum.repeatRevision = repeatRevision1 != null  ? repeatRevision1 : "";

Comment: note: to create Instance of Datum class use, Datum datum = Datum();

Comment: i add Datum datum = Datum():
but the problem still exist .@Ajith Ramsaran

Comment: error : Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Datum'. @Ajith Ramsaran

Comment: use Json2Dart (JD) to plugin or website to generate Datum Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anywhere in you code, define datum like this and initialize it.

```
Datum datum = Datum():
```

And remove `final`, because you want to change it's properties, this is not `final`, Should work.

Comment: error : Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Datum'

Answer (score 0):

use this site to convert your JSON response to dart model class with JSON decoder and encoder that's very good .
https://app.quicktype.io/
If there is a problem with converting and decoding JSON, it will be solved.

Comment: error : Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'Datum'

Comment: you should put an instance of JSON response in left side and choose dart language from combo box in right side